# Setting attribute in pageContext of Scriplet not available outside?

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

Given part of a JSP page:

```
<%! int index = 0; %>

<% int index = 1;
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String> () ;
strings.add(0, "Zero");
strings.add(1, "One");
strings.add(2, "Two");
pageContext.setAttribute("strings", strings);
index = 2;
%>
${strings[index]}
```

What will be the output?

I thought output would be "One" 
But output does not print anything.

As per my understanding variable set in the pageContext should be available outside as well. So I tried following

```
${pageContext.getAttribute(strings[index])}
```

Still no output. Please can someone guide me.

Comment: you need `pageContext.setAttribute("index",index);`` as well.

Comment: Yes there is pageContext.setAttribute("strings",strings); inside Scriptlet.

Answer (score 0):

Expression Language( EL) looks for [scopes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/PageDevGuide/html/s0203elvariablescopes01.html) and works with them, such as page, request, session or application scopes.

You set your array in page scope (it is the default scope) above but don't set the `index`. So it is not accessible for the EL. You need to set index variable in any scope as well.

```
int index = 1;
pageContext.setAttribute("strings", strings);
pageContext.setAttribute("index", index);
index = 2;
```

In this case, you should see `One` because the index that set the page scope is `1`.

You can also try it with JSTL:

```
<c:set var="index" scope="page" value="1"></c:set> // scope="page" already default
<c:set var="strings" value="${['Zero','One','Two']}"></c:set>
${strings[index]}
```

Comment: Oh so the problem is not Strings rather index. I thought as it is declared as <%! int index=0; %> so EL will take index from there. But I think I am wrong.